# How do I pass Arraylist object to makehttprequest as Namevaluepair

Tags: java, android, mysql, arraylist, android-asynctask

I am getting contacts details of each person from Constractcontact table and stored all of the contacts into arraylist object Which is `ArrayList<SavingContacts> contacts = new ArrayList<SavingContacts>();` then I sent this object to Asynctask for doing background work so these contacts stored into MySql database, I have a `makehttprequest(.............)` function which takes namevaluepair, but I want to send arraylist object to makehhtprequest as namevalue pair, but I couldnot do so,please Help me what can I do, And Where  am I  wrong,

**Given below is my code:**

```
This code is in oncreate function of **activity**

 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
   //   SavingContacts savingcontacts=new SavingContacts();
      ArrayList<SavingContacts> contacts = new ArrayList<SavingContacts>();
      Cursor = getContentResolver().query(
               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
               null, null,
               ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
      Log.d("database1" ,"17");
     if (Cursor.getCount() > 0)  {
           while (Cursor.moveToNext()) {
               SavingContacts savingcontacts=new SavingContacts();

                phone = Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
               if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)) {

                   Log.d("Your Location4", "ok4:");
                        name = Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        id = Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                       // photouri=Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO));
                        email=Cursor.getString(Cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                       System.out.println("contactId="+ id+ ", name=" + name + ", phoneNumber=" + phone+"Email="+email);
                       savingcontacts.savingcontact(id, name, phone, email);
                       contacts.add(savingcontacts);
               }

           }


              }
     Cursor.close();
     new LoadSavingInDatabase().execute(contacts);



  }
```

**AsyncTask class:**

```
 public  class LoadSavingInDatabase extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<SavingContacts>,String,String>{

      private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
      private static final String URL = "http://amiranzur.com/android_connect/create_product.php";

      JSONObject jsonObject= null;

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(ArrayList<SavingContacts>... param) {


          ArrayList<SavingContacts> contactArray = param[0];

         **`Please give some idea at this point what can I do so I can pass arraylist object to makehttp function.`**


          JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONParser().makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", ContactArray);// error 

      if(jsonObject != null){
          try {
              int success = jsonObject.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

              if (success == 1) {

                 Log.d("create","lpc");

                 bool = true;
                Log.d("insert","true" + bool); 
              } else {

              }
          } catch (JSONException e) {
              Log.d("exception","exc "+e);
              Log.d("create","lpc");
          }

      }
      else if(jsonObject == null){
          Log.d("null", "null1");
          bool = false;
      }


          return null;
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(boolean bool){
          if(bool == false)
          Log.d("Insertion failed", "ID already inserted");


      }


  }
```

Comment: plaese refer to http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: I already visited  this site, But they send namevalue pair one by one, but I want to send a arraylist object to makehttp request